# Why is the List in Codename one not showing all entries if there are many?

Tags: list, codenameone

I developed my own list in codename one with two possible entry types and two different renderer (one for each type of entry).

**I entered some hard-coded dummy entries into that list**

If I start the app in the **simulator**, all the dummy entries are **shown correctly**, but once I download the app onto my **phone** for testing purpose, I **can't scroll down the whole list**, but only like 20 entries (While the 'scroll bar' on the left of the list looks like it went down the whole list).

What could be the problem?

ps: As I don't use the GUIBuilder, the files are pretty big, so I will post the code of the two ListItems (+ abstract parent class), the two ListRenderer (+ abstract parent) and their usage only on demand.

**EDIT:**
having a closer look at the scroll bar, it looks like it does not calculate the screen size correctly (at least the last entries are off-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the list is not in a scrollable container.

Place it at the center of a BordarLayout container.

Comment: It's not a scrollable container and it's placed as the center of a container with BorderLayout.

(edit in my post)

Comment: Did you call `revalidate()` on the parent container after adding the list and its data?

Comment: No, I don't. How to and where?

Comment: At the end of the code that add the list component and populate its data with renderer, call `myList.getParent().revalidate()` or revalidate the whole form `f.revalidate()`.

Comment: okay, should `list.getParent().getParent().revalidate() ` work for the whole Form? (if it is the 'grandparent'?)

Comment: It may not, in that case... just call `f.revalidate();`

Comment: That thing with the revalidate worked! great, thank you